# ping gateway every 60 secs and save it to a log file including date and time

Tags: logs, ping

I want to set a ping command in Linux which has a 60 secs interval and save it to a log file including the date and time.

I can run the ping command with intervals and save it to the log file, but I don't have a date and time! Also, I don't want to type "ping 10.100.... -i 60 > log" in the terminal! I want Linux itself to do this! I just configure the Linux.

Comment: What have you done till now?

Comment: I don't know where should I set the configs!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
#! /bin/sh
export LANG=C TZ=UTC
( date; ping -c1 server.com ) >> /path/to/server.log
```

Exports are needed because it would be much easier to parse the log file.

Put it cron:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: I make a crontab using crontab -e and put the script into it but I got an error : 
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.DNHIPI/crontab":26: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n)

Comment: Anybody else knows?!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/797047/how-to-fix-bad-minute-error-while-installing-a-new-crontab https://cronitor.io/cron-reference/bad-minute-crontab-error

Comment: yes, I saw this but my problem isn't solved!

Comment: I knew what should I do (what you said at first) but it doesn't work!

Comment: It seems Okay and works. I appreciate Artem S. Tashkinov.